# ROC-AUC FPR FNR in Python and R?

Tags: python, r, roc, auc, false-positive

I have a dataframe object in R/Python that looks like:

```
df columns:
fraud = [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
score = [0.84, 1, 1.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.13, 0.32, 1.4, 0.9, 0.45]
```

When I use `roc_curve` in Python I get `fpr`, `fnr` and `thresholds`.

I have 2 questions, maybe a bit theoretical but please explain it to me:

1. Are these thresholds are calculated actually? I have calculated manually `fpr` and `fnr`, but are these thresholds = the score above?
2. How can I generate same `fpr`, `fnr` and `thresholds` in `R`?

Comment: How did you manually calculate fpr and fnr? What threshold did you use?

Comment: @pault I have used the 2nd point in fraud list - the first 0 was my threshold - under this threshold = false and greater = true.

Comment: @pault Correct me if I am wrong, I will use len(fraud) amount of thresholds and draw the roc?

Comment: I'm assuming `fraud` are the true labels and `score` is the output of some classification model. I don't know if this is how `roc_curve` is implemented (you can look at the source code if you'd like) but one could calculate TPR and FPR by varying the threshold over the values you have. Then use these pairs of (TPR, FPR) to plot the ROC curve.

Comment: I have a pair of TPR and FPR per threshold, correct me.
Do you know the answer for the second question?
Please post as answer. @pault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thresholds usually correspond to the value which maximizes tpr + tnr (sensitivity + specificity) this is called the Youden J index (tpr + tnr - 1) but has also several other names.

take the following example with Sonar dataset:

```
library(mlbench)
library(xgboost)
library(caret)
library(pROC)
data(Sonar)
```

lets fit a model on part of Sonar data and predict on another part:

```
ind <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train <- Sonar[ind,]
test <- Sonar[-ind,]
X = as.matrix(train[, -61])
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data = X, label = as.numeric(train$Class)-1)
dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(test[, -61]))
```

fit the model on the train data:

```
model = xgb.train(data = dtrain, 
                  eval = "auc",
                  verbose = 0,  maximize = TRUE, 
                  params = list(objective = "binary:logistic",
                                eta = 0.1,
                                max_depth = 6,
                                subsample = 0.8,
                                lambda = 0.1 ), 
                  nrounds = 10)

preds <- predict(model, dtest)
true <- as.numeric(test$Class)-1


plot(roc(response = true,
         predictor =  preds,
         levels=c(0, 1)),
     lwd=1.5, print.thres = T, print.auc = T, print.auc.y = 0.5)
```

[image]

So if you set the threshold at 0.578 you will maximize the value `tpr + tnr` and the values in the parenthesis on the plot are tpr and tnr. Verify:

```
sensitivity(as.factor(ifelse(preds > 0.578, "1", "0")), as.factor(true))
#output
[1] 0.9090909
specificity(as.factor(ifelse(preds > 0.578, "1", "0")), as.factor(true))\
#output
[1] 0.7586207
```

you could create prediction over many possible thresholds:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply((1:1000)/1000, function(x){
  sens <- sensitivity(as.factor(ifelse(preds > x, "1", "0")), as.factor(true))
  spec <- specificity(as.factor(ifelse(preds > x, "1", "0")), as.factor(true))
  data.frame(sens, spec)
})) -> thresh
```

and now:

```
thresh[which.max(rowSums(thresh)),]
#output
         sens      spec
560 0.9090909 0.7586207
```

You can also check this out:

```
thresh[555:600,]
```

That being said, usually when considering financial data, not just the class is if off interested but also the cost associated with false predictions which is usually not the same for false negatives and false positives. So these models are fit using cost-sensitive classification. [More on the mater](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/cost_sensitive_classif/index.html).
On another note, when deciding on the threshold, you should do it either on cross validated data or on a validation set specifically designated for the task. If you use it one the test set that inevitably leads to over-optimistic predictions.